# Split a CSV-style string with Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I have data from a CSV file that's already loaded into memory. So I might have something like this:

```
csv_string = 'Value 1,Value 2,"Hey, it\'s value 3!",Value 4 has "some quotes"'
```

Obviously I won't want to do `csv_string.split(",")`. Since it seems like splitting a CSV-style string this way might be a not-all-that-uncommon need, I was wondering if there's a solution already out there.

Comment: Forgive me, but why do you not want to split on comma?  It is not clear from the example.

Comment: Because his data could contain commas, though they'd be delimited (hopefully).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For parsing CSV, Ruby comes with the [`csv`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/csv/1.9.2/frames/) library:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.parse(csv_string)
# => [['Value 1', 'Value 2', "Hey, it's value 3!", 'Value 4 has "some quotes"']]
```

Unfortunately, your string doesn't actually contain valid CSV, so what you'll *really* get is the following exception:

```
# CSV::MalformedCSVError: Illegal quoting on line 1.
```

Since your data doesn't actually conform to any common standard, there can obviously not be a common parser and you'll have to write your own.

Alternatively, you could change your data to be valid CSV, for example like this:

```
c = %q[Value 1,Value 2,"Hey, it's value 3!","Value 4 has ""some quotes"""]

CSV.parse(c)
# => [['Value 1', 'Value 2', "Hey, it's value 3!", 'Value 4 has "some quotes"']]
```

Answer (score 0):

on Ruby 1.9.x FasterCSV is the default csv engine, if you are using 1.8.x you will need to include the gem, but take a look at the foreach and row parsing abilities:
http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/